# Serving multiple sites with gunicorn and nginx?

Tags: python, django, nginx

I'm trying to serve both a Django and a Flask site using gunicorn and nginx. The Django site is currently available at example.com, and I'd like for the Flask site to be availabe at myapp.example.com .

My nginx configuration file is as follows for the Django site:

```
cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com 
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location /static {
        alias /home/me/sites/example.com/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/example.com.socket;
    }
}
```

I also have a second nginx config file for the Flask site:

```
cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp.example.com 
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.example.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

I'm pretty sure that I want to change my proxy_pass variable, but am not sure what I should change it to.

My gunicorn file currently is as follows:

```
description "Gunicorn server for example.com"

start on net-device-up
stop on shutdown

respawn

setuid me
chdir /home/rowan/sites/example.com/source

exec ../virtualenv/bin/gunicorn \
    --bind unix:/tmp/example.com.socket \
    example.com.wsgi:application
```

Do I need a second gunicorn config file for the Flask site? Which I would then put in `/etc/init/` and start through the `sudo start gunicorn-myapp.example.com` command?

Comment: ... Yes? What is your question?

Comment: What I should change the proxy_pass variable to for the flask application, whether I need a second gunicorn config file, and what the correct way is to start the second gunicorn service. More generally, what the workflow looks like for serving both apps with gunicorn.

Comment: But you seem to know that you do. example.com is proxying to upstream via the "/tmp/example.com.socket" socket, and gunicorn is binding to that socket; whereas myapp.example.com is proxying to http://127.0.0.1:8001, so you need another gunicorn binding to that address.